# Choquet Theorem and Rudin RCA problem 5.12

Tags: real-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $K$ be a triangle (two-dimensional figure) in the plane, let $H$ be the set consisting of the vertices of $K$, and let $A$ be the set of all real functions $f$ on $K$, of the form
$$
f(x, y) = \alpha x + \beta y + \gamma, \quad (\alpha, \beta,\gamma \in\mathbb{R}\ ).
$$
Show that to each $(x_0, y_0)  \in K $ there corresponds a unique measure $\mu$ on $H$ such that
$$
f(x_0, y_0) = \int_H fd\mu.
$$
(Compare Sec. 5.22.)

Replace $K$ by a square, let $H$ again be the set of its vertices, and let $A$ be as above. Show that to
each point of $K$ there still corresponds a measure on $H$, with the above property, but that uniqueness
is now lost.
Can you extrapolate to a more general theorem? (Think of other figures, higher dimensional
spaces.)

I can prove the exist but Cannot figure out the **uniqueness** and the **general theorem**.

Comment: Generalization: Choquet Theorem.See  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choquet_theory

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, Thanks reply. Is the uniqueness of triangle because that the point in a triangle can only be linear combination of the vertices. But for square, we can find two set of vertices to represent this point? Is my thought correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for Kavi Rama Murthy comments.
The triangle and square just a special case of The Choquet_theory.
The form of function in $A$ just are liner. The interior value can be represented by its vertices. As in triangle there is only uniqueness but for square there two.